# cv2.MORPH_CLOSE joining letters together

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-morphology

I'm using Opencv to do some morphological operations on an image:
[image: input] 
but it joins some of the letters together creating problems when I detect it's contours. For example:

[image: joined letters]

Is there some tweaking I can do wih my code to fix this or will I have to do this a different way?(but it has to be a closing algorithm or function because it is pretty helpful in preprocessing).

My code I am using is as below:

```
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(opening, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
```

Comment: Could you explain why do you need mathematical morphology ? If you only need the contours you can do a thresholding using `cv2.threshold` based on Otsu method.
In order to make the letters white you just do a `cv2.bitwise_not` and then you can directly apply `cv2.findContours`.
If you are looking for a thinning approach OpenCV's module `ximgproc` does have a thinning function that you can try.
Considering the code you wrote rather than a closing operator try a erosion.

Comment: I need morphology as some of the letters get broken up in thresholding because of the marker being weak in some places

Comment: Thresholding in OpenCV does not use marker, it use a value (or an algorithm to determine the value) to define what use to be the background and what use to be the foreground.
In the image you share all the letters are well separated so there no reason that change.
Actually I check from my side based on the image you shared and all the letters stay well separated.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be like that here

Comment: Try to do that:

    import numpy as np
    import cv2
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
    
    I = cv2.imread('words.jpg',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    
    _,It = cv2.threshold(I,0.,255,cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    It = cv2.bitwise_not(It)
    _,ctrs,_ = cv2.findContours(It,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    Id = cv2.drawContours(cv2.merge((It,It,It)),ctrs,-1,(0xFF,0,0))

Comment: it makes too many contours then

Comment: This is something else.
You can adjust the second parameter to `findContours` or take a look to     `cv2.connectedComponents` and then apply `findContours` for each labels with the second parameters as `cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL`.
The second option will only keep the external contour of each letter.

Comment: no still not working

Comment: Take a look here:
http://answers.opencv.org/question/197080/opencv-findcountours-is-not-find-all-contours/

Comment: that seems to work. you can post it as an answer

Comment: I was using CHAIN_APPROX_NONE

Comment: I do not think that in your particular case it does change anything but however I prefer to keep SIMPLE than NONE.

Comment: Well it did change for me

Comment: I am surprise. For my information what does change between the two options ?

Comment: It doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is workable solution:

```
  import numpy as np
  import cv2
  from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

  I = cv2.imread('/home/smile/Downloads/words.jpg',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

  _,It = cv2.threshold(I,0.,255,cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
  It = cv2.bitwise_not(It)
  _,labels = cv2.connectedComponents(I)

  result = np.zeros((I.shape[0],I.shape[1],3),np.uint8)

  for i in range(labels.min(),labels.max()+1):
     mask = cv2.compare(labels,i,cv2.CMP_EQ)

     _,ctrs,_ = cv2.findContours(mask,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

     result = cv2.drawContours(result,ctrs,-1,(0xFF,0,0))

  plt.figure()
  plt.imshow(result)    
  plt.axis('off')
```

During the two first steps the image is binarize and reverse in order to make the letters appear has white over black.

```
_,It = cv2.threshold(I,0.,255,cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
It = cv2.bitwise_not(It)
```

[image: bin]

Then during the next step each letter become a labelized region.

```
_,labels = cv2.connectedComponents(I)
```

[image: labels]

The final step consist for each label value to find the area in the image that correspond to it, process the external contour of that area and "draw" it in the output image.

```
result = np.zeros((I.shape[0],I.shape[1],3),np.uint8)

for i in range(labels.min(),labels.max()+1):
   mask = cv2.compare(labels,i,cv2.CMP_EQ)

   _,ctrs,_ = cv2.findContours(mask,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

   result = cv2.drawContours(result,ctrs,-1,(0xFF,0,0)
```

Hope it helps.